# Select and aggregate last records base on order

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have different versions of the charges in a table.  I want to grab and sum the last charge grouped by Type.

So I want to add 9.87, 9.63, 1.65.

I want the Parent ID , sum(9.87 + 9.63 + 1.65) as the results of this query.

We use MSSQL

```
ID  ORDER   CHARGES     TYPE    PARENT ID           
1   1       6.45        1       1
2   2       1.25        1       1
3   3       9.87        1       1
4   1       6.54        2       1
5   2       5.64        2       1
6   3       0.84        2       1
7   4       9.63        2       1
8   1       7.33        3       1
9   2       5.65        3       1
10  3       8.65        3       1
11  4       5.14        3       1
12  5       1.65        3       1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
WITH recordsList
AS
(
    SELECT Type, Charges,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PArtition BY TYPE
                                ORDER BY [ORDER] DESC) rn
    FROM tableName
)
SELECT  SUM(Charges) totalCharge
FROM recordsLIst
WHERE rn = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a4488/1)

Answer (score 3):

Use `row_number()` to identify the rows to be summed, and then sum them:

```
select SUM(charges)
from (select t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION by type order by id desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could use a window aggregate `MAX()`:

```
SELECT SUM(Charges)
FROM (
  SELECT
    [ORDER],
    Charges,
    MaxOrder = MAX([ORDER]) OVER (PARTITION BY [TYPE])
  FROM atable
) s
WHERE [ORDER] = MaxOrder
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.PARENT_ID, SUM(t.CHARGES)
FROM dbo.test73 t
WHERE EXISTS (
              SELECT 1
              FROM dbo.test73
              WHERE [TYPE] = t.[TYPE]
              HAVING MAX([ORDER]) = t.[ORDER]
              )
GROUP BY t.PARENT_ID
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/73b0c/1/0)